# Add Record Editing first record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

In Access 2013, when I drag the name field from my table into a form and add the add record button, the text input/form display the first record. When I change the text input and hit the add record button, it changes the name of the first record. After that it behaves normal and add new records. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the form for adding new records then set the form's `Data Entry` property to `Yes`:

[image: DataEntry.png]

For more details on that property look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845109.aspx).